# SSH Agent forward to docker container in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, ssh, ssh-agent

I am using SSH agent forwarding to connect to my hosting and the application is dockerized. I now want to forward the agent on to docker, so from local -> server -> docker. Agent forwarding from local to serve is working, what should be done for the next step?

Comment: have you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You may set up a ssh server in the container, and then use ProxyJump to forward the agent.

```
ssh -A -J <server_ip> <container_ip>
```

Or, in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host Server
    Hostname <server_ip>

Host App
    Hostname <container_ip>
    ProxyJump Server
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Then, `ssh App` to connect and forward your agent to the container.